# Cython Error Installing Reddit on a Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, clang, virtualenv, cython, reddit

I'm working through the issues trying to install Reddit on a Mac OS X.

I realize this is most easily done through a VirtualBox install on Ubuntu. Indeed, I have that running already. However, I want to run the PyCharm Python IDE locally and have these talk to the Virtual Box Ubuntu servers running everything that's not Python code for the web server itself.

So please don't suggest that I not do what I'm attempting. I already understand this is a non-trivial task for someone with my level of python experience.

Here's my current blocker during the install:

```
python setup.py build
```

in the `/reddit/r2` directory, I get the following errors:

```
(dev)HS:r2 inflector$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'lib.python2.7.site-packages.Cython.Runtime.refnanny' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/./lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: './lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.c'
clang: error: no input files
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Note that I am running a virtualenv and have installed all the python modules required already. I have also done a full manual install of Cython which already compiled refnanny successfully once.

```
pip freeze
```

shows

```
Cython==0.19.1
```

The last bit of the clang parameters the -o option seems odd and may be the problem. It reads:

`-o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/./lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.o`

Note the `/./` just after `intel-2.7` and before `/lib/`. This doesn't seem correct but seems like an artifact of the virtualenv setup.

Any ideas what is wrong and how I can get setup.py to run without causing this error?

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid answer and you have already tried it, but it seems your missing `refnanny.c` which you could just [download from here](http://cython.org/release/Cython-0.15.1/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.c) and stick it in `Cython/Runtime/`. This has worked for me in similar problems.

Comment: The refnanny.c file was compiled when I installed Cython, and then removed for some reason. I've been able to narrow this down to cython not getting called properly on the *.pyx files in Reddit. I ran cython on these files and seem to have a workaround for this problem. I'd still like to know why it's not calling cython as part of the install, however.